# Two Azure App Services on single domain

Tags: azure, web-deployment, azure-web-app-service

I have two web apps:
1. UI Project
2. API Project

They should map in next way: UI Project -> mydomain.com, API Project -> mydomain.com/api

Do you have any ideas as to how I can do it?

I don't want to have a virtual application or a virtual directory, because they can't be configured and scaled separately. 
I expected that the load on the API Project will be more than on the UI project. As a result I would like to configure the price plan and the scalability in a different way for each project.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

According to your requirement, I suggest you could try use url redirect in your 
UI web app's web config file.

By using this way, if customer access the mydomain.com/api, it will auto redirect to your azure web api app's url.

Notice: after redirecting, the url show in the browser will be changed.

More details about how to set it , you could refer to this [article](http://zainrizvi.io/2016/04/07/block-default-azure-websites-domain/).

Another way, you could consider using azure application gateway, it now support web app as its backend pool.

More details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-create-url-route-portal).

About how to use web app as its backend pool, refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-web-app-powershell).

Comment: Hi, thank you for you comment with useful links. 
They are really intereste.
About my question. I would like to resolve this question without add addition resources, because they required additional cost.
About redirect, I thought about it and think it will require one more resource.
Same results for gateway.
In any case thank you for you answer.

Comment: Do you mean you used one app service plan with two web app now? Then you want each web app could be configurable and scalability in separated way? The url redirect just change the main web app's web config. It doesn't need any other resources.

Comment: Yep, but how I understand each request will come to main app and then it redirect on the second one. Is it correct?
If yes, that mean in any case the first app will take part of loading for second application. As result if I will have a lot of calls the first app will be under loading for redirect on the second one.

Comment: Yes, the request will firstly go to the first application. But if you don't want to use this and not want to create another resources, there are no way to achieve your requirement.